# Imagemagic focus on area

Tags: focus, imagemagick, crop, blur

I've been searching information about how to create focus on area of image using Imagemagick. I haven't founded anything in official documentation.

I would like to blur all the image except area, which is determined by the coordinates.
Help please!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script with 3 steps (you could compact these steps in a single command but it would be harder to explain, so I'll keep it split):

1. create a completely blurred version of your original image
2. create a mask in which you define the 'focused' zone, for example a rectangle
3. apply your mask to the blurred image to obtain the final image in which all the pixels are blurred but the ones inside the rectangle defined in the mask

```
convert original.png -blur 10x8 imagefuzz.png
convert original.png -fill white -draw "color 0,0 reset" -fill black -draw "rectangle 100,100,350,250" mask.png
convert original.png imagefuzz.png mask.png -composite output.png
```